# Undefined when returning 'results' parameter from mysql query

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to send data to **EJS** from **MySQL** Databases using **Node.js** and **Express**, but it shows error when returning 'results' parameter:

```
function dbData(){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM clients', (err, results, fields)=>{
        return results;
    });
}
```

**Route:**

```
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    let data = dbData(); 
    console.log(data);
});
```

And when going to **localhost:3000**, the console shows:

[image: undefined]

The thing is that when i console log the results:

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM clientes', (err, results, fields)=>{
        console.log(results);
        return results;
    });
```

The console shows:

[image: array console.log]

So why ***data*** is equal to 'undefined' if i'm returning the 'results' array? and how can i solve this?

I'm new in Node.js, sorry if this is too obvious :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, the documentation for [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#introduction) - a pure node.js JavaScript Client that implements the MySQL protocol, says in its very first topics that you should not return anything from `connection.query()` method.

This said,

```js
function dbData(){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM clients', (err, results, fields)=>{
        return results;
    });
}
```

was supposed to be without any `return` (or just `return;`)

```js
function dbData(){
   connection.query('SELECT * FROM clients', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log('The solution is: ', results);
    });
}
```

So when you do `console.log(data)` you are actually printing undefined because it isn't supposed to return a thing. If you want to take the result out of the query, you should consider using a callback.

```js
function dbData(callback){
   connection.query('SELECT * FROM clients', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      callback(results);
    });
}

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    dbData(data => {
        console.log(data);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, solved <3. I'll study this a little bit more. Have great day.